# Dynamically generate interface using ScriptableObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, data-oriented-design, scriptable-object

#### Hello fellas!

Currently working on an AR application, I am learning and playing around with the **ScriptableObjects**.

With a little to no programming background (less than an effective year), I am struggling a little bit on some parts.


I am trying to **create a frame**, for a "home-made" video player, with interactive elements (aka buttons).

So far, both the sprites and external links for theses buttons *(social media, shops, websites)* are stored inside **ScriptableObjects** *(same goes for the frame's sprite, and the video player related elements, such as the renderTexture or the videoClip)*.


I would like to go further, by creating a prefab letting me choose the number of buttons and their positioning.

For example, let say I have to create 2 different video players :

- VideoPlayer_A the player and the frame, and 3 buttons (facebook, twitter and website)
- VideoPlayer_B the player and the frame, and 2 buttons (facebook and website)

How can I achieve this, considering that the buttons (either be it 1, 2 or 4 -maximum-) must hold and have equal space on top of the frame (see screenshot bellow).
The final goal is to have a very modular system, creating frames according to the data I have.

As a final note, I am not asking for the "already made" solution, but more for the path to achieve what I am looking to. As I am still learning, I am looking for hints, "ways to do" but not directly the solution.

Thanks, by advance ;)

[image: <blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/JWth6m0" data-context="false" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/JWth6m0"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>]

Comment: Maybe using a [`HorizontalLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html)?

Comment: Oh, grid system! OK, I will be looking in this direction! That's a first step, thanks!